# Is there anything significant about GAP's SmallGroup(512,2045)?

Tags: finite-groups

Here's the output of the GAP command "SmallGroupsInformation(512)"

> There are 10494213 groups of order 512.
>
> ```
> 1 is cyclic. 
> 2 - 10 have rank 2 and p-class 3.
> 11 - 386 have rank 2 and p-class 4.
> 387 - 1698 have rank 2 and p-class 5.
> 1699 - 2008 have rank 2 and p-class 6.
> 2009 - 2039 have rank 2 and p-class 7.
> 2040 - 2044 have rank 2 and p-class 8.
> 2045 has rank 3 and p-class 2.
> 2046 - 29398 have rank 3 and p-class 3.
> 29399 - 30617 have rank 3 and p-class 4.
> 30618 - 31239 have rank 3 and p-class 3.
> 31240 - 56685 have rank 3 and p-class 4.
> 56686 - 60615 have rank 3 and p-class 5.
> 60616 - 60894 have rank 3 and p-class 6.
> 60895 - 60903 have rank 3 and p-class 7.
> 60904 - 67612 have rank 4 and p-class 2.
> 67613 - 387088 have rank 4 and p-class 3.
> 387089 - 419734 have rank 4 and p-class 4.
> 419735 - 420500 have rank 4 and p-class 5.
> 420501 - 420514 have rank 4 and p-class 6.
> 420515 - 6249623 have rank 5 and p-class 2.
> 6249624 - 7529606 have rank 5 and p-class 3.
> 7529607 - 7532374 have rank 5 and p-class 4.
> 7532375 - 7532392 have rank 5 and p-class 5.
> 7532393 - 10481221 have rank 6 and p-class 2.
> 10481222 - 10493038 have rank 6 and p-class 3.
> 10493039 - 10493061 have rank 6 and p-class 4.
> 10493062 - 10494173 have rank 7 and p-class 2.
> 10494174 - 10494200 have rank 7 and p-class 3.
> 10494201 - 10494212 have rank 8 and p-class 2.
> 10494213 is elementary abelian.
> ```
>
> This size belongs to layer 7 of the SmallGroups library.
>
> IdSmallGroup is not available for this size.

Even if I only barely know what "rank" and "p-class" are, 2045 on that list stands out.  Is there any other way to describe it?  For example, is it the Sylow subgroup of any simple group?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is the "free" group of nilpotency class at most $2$, exponent dividing $4$, on three generators. (In other words, every group in that class is a quotient of it.)

According to

https://etd.ohiolink.edu/rws_etd/document/get/osu1086112148/inline

(ON SYLOW $2$-SUBGROUPS OF FINITE SIMPLE GROUPS OF ORDER UP TO $2^{10}$, Sergey Malyushitsky, M.S. Thesis, The Ohio State University)

it is not the Sylow $2$-subgroup of a finite simple group.

In general, the "free" group of nilpotency class at most $2$ and exponent at most $4$ on $d$ generators has order $4^d\cdot 2^{\binom{d}{2}}$. So, for example, you should see a similar phenomena at order 32, where there is a unique group of rank $2$ and $p$-class $2$.